# Warning meassage: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r, regression

I got warnings when running this code.

For example, when I put 
`tm1<- summary(tmfit)[c(4,8,9)]`, 
I can get the result, but I need to run this code for each $i$.

Why do I get this error?

Is there any way to do this instead of via a `for` loop?

Specifically, I have many regressants ($y$) with the same two regressors ($x$'s).

How I can get these results of regression analysis(to make some comparisons)?

```
dreg=read.csv("dayreg.csv")
fundr=read.csv("fundreturnday.csv")
num=ncol(fundr)
exr=dreg[,2]
tm=dreg[,4]
for(i in 2:num)
{
  tmfit=lm(fundr[,i]~exr+tm)
  tm1[i]<- summary(tmfit)[c(4,8,9)]
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try storing your result into a list instead of a vector.

```
dreg=read.csv("dayreg.csv")
fundr=read.csv("fundreturnday.csv")
num=ncol(fundr)
exr=dreg[,2]
tm = list()
for(i in 2:num)
{
  tmfit=lm(fundr[,i]~exr+tm)
  tm1[[i]]<- summary(tmfit)[c(4,8,9)]
}
```

You can look at an element in the list like so

```
tm1[[2]]
```

Comment: @jsk.Thank you for your answer.Another qestion :you konw summary(tmfit) is a recursive list of length 11.I want save tm1(including three items :coefficients,r-aquared,adj.r-squared) into a csv file ,but I get the messy file.why ?code:write.csv(tm1,"tm_reg.csv")

Comment: Hi Jacky, please post this as a separate question on the site. Thanks